# Behavior of the sum $\sum_p e^{-p^2 \pi x}$ around 0 and $+\infty$

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series

A formula found by Jacobi for $\psi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n^2\pi x}$ says
$$\psi(\frac{1}{x})=\sqrt{x} \psi(x)+\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{2}$$

If we define
$$\phi(x)=\sum_p e^{-p^2\pi x}$$
where $p$ runs through all prime numbers. Now we want to know the behavior of this function near 0 and $+\infty$, then what can be told? Does there exist a similar relation like this
$$\phi(\frac{1}{x})=\sqrt{x} \phi(x)+f(x)$$
where $f(x)$ is easy to handle?

Comment: I assume you mean $\phi(1/x) = \sqrt{x} \phi(x) + f(x)$?

Comment: Mellin transform of $\phi(x)$ is the so called Prime Zeta Function http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html

Comment: You can get a functional equation for $\sum_{n \ge 2} \Lambda(n) e^{-\pi n^2 x}$ and  $\sum_{n \ge 2} \frac{\Lambda(n)}{\ln n} e^{-\pi n^2 x}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no Jacobi-like functional equation for your $\phi(x)$. Nevertheless, with a bit of analysis, we can determine its asymptotic behavior as $x\to\infty$ and as $x\to 0+$.

When $x>0$ is large, the leading term $p=2$ dominates, so we have the asymptotics
$$\phi(x)\sim e^{-4\pi x},\qquad x\to\infty.$$

When $x>0$ is small, we use the prime number theorem in the form
$$\pi(x)\sim\mathrm{Li}(x):=\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log t}.$$
Using this result and integration by parts, we get, as $x\to 0+$,
\begin{align*} \phi(x)&=\int_{2-}^\infty e^{-t^2\pi x}\,d\pi(t)
=\int_2^\infty \pi(t)\,d(-e^{-t^2\pi x})\\
&\sim \int_2^\infty \mathrm{Li}(t)\,d(-e^{-t^2\pi x})
=\int_2^\infty e^{-t^2\pi x}\,d\,\mathrm{Li}(t)
=\int_2^\infty e^{-t^2\pi x}\,\frac{dt}{\log t}.
\end{align*}
Making the change of variable $t=u/\sqrt{x}$ in the last integral, we get
$$\phi(x)\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\int_{2\sqrt{x}}^\infty e^{-u^2\pi}\frac{du}{\log(u/\sqrt{x})},\qquad x\to 0+.$$
Now the denominator $\log(u/\sqrt{x})$ always exceeds $2$, but for the bulk of the integral it is $\sim\log(1/\sqrt{x})$. More precisely, with the notation $r(x)=\sqrt{\log(1/x)}$, we can estimate the integral as
\begin{align*} 
\int_{2\sqrt{x}}^\infty e^{-u^2\pi}\frac{du}{\log(u/\sqrt{x})}&=\int_{2\sqrt{x}}^{\exp(-r(x))}+\int_{\exp(-r(x))}^{\exp(r(x))}+\int_{\exp(r(x))}^\infty\\[8pt]
&=O(e^{-r(x)})+\frac{1+o(1)}{\log(1/\sqrt{x})}\int_{\exp(-r(x))}^{\exp(r(x))}e^{-u^2\pi}\,du+O(e^{-r(x)})\\[8pt]
&=\frac{1/2+o(1)}{\log(1/\sqrt{x})}=\frac{1+o(1)}{\log(1/x)}.
\end{align*}
Hence we have proved that
$$ \phi(x)\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}\log(1/x)},\qquad x\to 0+.$$

Comment: I am really not seeing this decay rate at $0$ experimentally...

Comment: @IgorRivin: Well, this is not a decay rate, but a blowup rate. Do you see experimentally the $1/(2\sqrt{x})$ blowup rate for $\psi(x)$ when $x\to 0+$? For $\phi(x)$ the result is natural in the light of this, since the density of primes around $n\approx 1/\sqrt{x}$ is approximately $\log(1/\sqrt{x})$.

Comment: Sorry, blow-up rate. No, I am not seeing it (though this might be due to computational issues) -  here are the values: $f(10^{-7}) = -0.0772, f(10^{-6}) = -0.092, f(10^{-5}) = -0.114, f(10^{-4}) = -0.146, f((10^{-3}) = -0.192, f(10^{-2} = -0.233, $

Comment: Notice that the blow-up seems sublinear in $\log x.$

Comment: @IgorRivin: Well, the asymptotics for $\phi(x)$ seems to kick in slowly, probably due to irregularities of the primes. Let us restrict the sums to $1\leq n\leq x^{-0.51}$ and to $1\leq p\leq x^{-0.51}$. Then with SAGE I get for $x=10^{-12}$ that $\psi(x)\approx 499523$ and $\phi(x)\approx 41087$. The first one is in very good agreement with $(2\sqrt{x})^{-1}$, the second one is in reasonable agreement with $(\sqrt{x}\log(1/x))^{-1}$.

Comment: @IgorRivin: Also, as I decrease $x$ from $10^{-4}$ to $10^{-12}$, the ratio of the experimental $\psi(x)$ and the predicted $(\sqrt{x}\log(1/x))^{-1}$ steadily goes down from $1.344$ to $1.135$.

Comment: @GH from MO, thanks for your wonderful analysis!

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just an experiment: If you define

$$f(x) = \varphi(1/x) - \sqrt{x} \varphi(x),$$

First, here is the graph of $f(x)$ between $0.00001$ and $0.1:$
[image]

And here is one between $0.01$ and $10:$[image]

Does not look like a nice function to me, but I am just a caveman (plus, computing this function is non-trivial)...

Secondly, $f(x)$ does seem to be approaching a limit as $x\to 0,$ the limit seems to be slightly negative (my guess is around $-0.05$)

Comment: I am typing an answer determining the asymptotics. Stay tuned.

Comment: @GHfromMO Waiting with bated breath!

Comment: I added my answer. I hope it is fine as I typed it fast.

Comment: @Igor Rivin, good job!